# R overlay counties (or othr options for county_choropleth)

Tags: r, choroplethr

Using some code I've gotten from StackOverflow, I would like to shade a map but also have the county name as well.

In a perfect world, I'd like to be able to show ONLY the top and bottom 5 county names and as an additional twist I'd like the high names in red and low names in black.

But I'm having enough trouble getting any names on or finding any examples of other options to add.

I'm new to R and not sure if this is the right way to do it.

Also, is there a visualization you would recommend to show 3 variables (income, birth rates, population) by county like this?

Thank you

```
library(noncensus)  
library(zipcode)    
library(choroplethr)
library(ggplot2)  
library(sp)
library(maps)

#this guy is pretty but needs county names
data(df_pop_county)
county_choropleth(df_pop_county,
                  title="US 2012 County Population Estimates",
                  legend="Population",
                  buckets=1,
                  zoom=c("new york"))

#this guy has county names
getLabelPoint <- # Returns a county-named list of label points
  function(county) {Polygon(county[c('long', 'lat')])@labpt}
df <- map_data('county', 'new york')                 # NY region county data
centroids <- by(df, df$subregion, getLabelPoint)     # Returns list
centroids <- do.call("rbind.data.frame", centroids)  # Convert to Data Frame
names(centroids) <- c('long', 'lat')                 # Appropriate Header
map('county', 'new york')
text(centroids$long, centroids$lat, rownames(centroids), offset=0, cex=0.4)
```

Comment: Please take a look here: and let me know if it helps you: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/choroplethr/county$20name/choroplethr/1BDEcSlQOr8/yjPe5dR0s3AJ.

Comment: No, that link brings me to apartments for rent in dubai.

Comment: Sorry - I don't have an explanation for why the link I copied from my address bar in google groups now redirects elsewhere.  But please try this instead: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/choroplethr/1BDEcSlQOr8. I once helped someone with a similar problem in the choroplethr forums, and was ondering if it would help you here.

Comment: I thought you were just pointing out a good investment opportunity. :) I think that might do it, unfortunately I won't get back to it for a while.